# SQL Aliasing with Statistical Functions not working

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Google Standard SQL with Big Query. I have the following code to get a variance and standard deviation from a table, however, the aliasing is not working. The column names return as `f0` and `f1` and not Variance and StdDev.

```
#StandardSQL

SELECT VARIANCE(Results) AS Variance, 
       STDDEV(Results) AS StdDev
  FROM `totals`
```

Screenshot of output

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works as expected for me.

Comment: Are you using Big Query with Standard SQL or other SQL implementation?

Comment: #StandardSQL indeed

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa please see original question with screenshot of output

Comment: Thanks for the partial screenshot. Can you post a screenshot that includes the query you ran?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa please see original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this apparent problem because the query is overwriting a table that previously had those column names.

If you do a

```
SELECT * FROM `bikes-data.bikes_data.var_and_stddev`
```

you'll find out that the table has the correct column names.

Somewhere on the display code the previous column names were cached, but your query is working as expected. You can also solve this problem by refreshing your browser tab.

I filed this as a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128651254.